# Add model relation to ModelForm before saving

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Article

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['content']
```

In my web application, the author logs in and writes an article. So clearly, when the author is presented with an ArticleForm, he/she does not need to fill  in the author field in the ArticleForm because the application already knows who the author is through the use of session variables.

This is the way I tried to add the author:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .models import Article
from .forms import ArticleForm

@login_required
def new_article(request):
    author_name = request.session['author_name']
    author = Author.objects.get(name=author_name)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.author = author  # I suspect the mistake is here
            # I also tried form.author = author.id
            form.save()
            return redirect('success')
    else:
        form = ArticleForm()

    return render(request, 'writings/new_article.html', {'form': form})
```

When I look at the database table, the author_id column is always `NULL`. What is wrong with my approach? How do I add a model relation before saving a ModelForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the object returned from `form.save(commit=False)` and modify that rather than the form. EG:

```
if form.is_valid():
    article = form.save(commit=False)
    article.author = author
    article.save()
    return redirect('success')
```